# How to Add Values to an Array on the off diagonal in Python?

Tags: python, r, numpy

```
B <- matrix(0, S, S)
diag(B) <- -s
  
  for (i in 2:S) { # i is rows
      for(j in 1:(i-1)){ #j is colums
          a <- 1
          b<- 2
      
          B[i,j]<- a
          B[j,i] <-b    
      }  
  }
```

This is a code I have used to create an array in R. Where I can determine the off diagonal numbers independently.  SO `B[i,j]<- a` does the lower off diagonal and `B[j,i] <-b` does the upper off diagonal.

However, I can't figure out how to do that in Python.
I started by setting up like this by writing this function, but I haven't gotten anywhere near as the set up in r. I would love to set up a for loop in which I can assign values in the off diagonal (upper and lower independently.

```
def get_A (S,s,sigma):
    A = np.zeros((S, S)) # create a matrix with all 0 in it
    # check the type of matrix
    print(A.dtype)

    for i in range (1,S):
        for j in range(i-1):
            A[i, j] = 1
            A[j, i] = 2

    return A
```

Comment: Draw out the matrix

Comment: Assuming `S = 3`, your code example will get `array([[0., 0., 2.], [0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.]])`, are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Using *Numpy* you can do it the following way:

```
n = 5    # Number of rows / columns
arr = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)  # Create an array, initially filled with zeroes
arr[np.triu_indices(n, k=1)] = 1   # Set the "upper triangle" elements to 1
arr[np.tril_indices(n, k=-1)] = 2  # Set the "lower triangle" elements to 1
```

The result is:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 0]])
```

Maybe you should read about *triu_indices* and *tril_indices* functions.

Answer (score 0):

With R and python you do not need for-loops:

in R:

```
B = matrix(1,S,S)
B - diag(S) + upper.tri(B)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    2    2    2
[2,]    1    0    2    2    2
[3,]    1    1    0    2    2
[4,]    1    1    1    0    2
[5,]    1    1    1    1    0
```

in Python:

```
B = np.ones((S,S))
B - np.eye(S) + np.triu(B, 1)

array([[0., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 0., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to assign different values to the diagonal and upper and lower triangles, but from your example code, you don't seem to know that `range()` is closed on the left and open on the right.

To assign values through the for loop, you can:

```
def get_A(S, s, sigma):
    A = np.zeros((S, S))
    
    for i in range(S):
        A[i, i] = s
    for i in range(1, S):
        for j in range(i):
            A[i, j] = 1
            A[j, i] = 2
    return A
```

When input is `get_A(3, 0, 0)` (I don't know what sigma means), you will get:

```
array([[0., 2., 2.],
       [1., 0., 2.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

A simpler and faster way is to use `np.indices` and bool mask array:

```
def get_A(S, s, sigma):
    A = np.diag(np.repeat(s, S))
    i, j = np.indices(A.shape)

    A[i > j] = 1
    A[i < j] = 2

    return A
```

As shown in the answer with the highest score, use `np.triu_indices` and `np.tril_indices` are better than this.

**Update:**

For the work you mentioned in the comment area, it seems that there is no need to use loops. There are simpler methods:

```
def get_A(S, s, sigma):
    A = sigma * np.abs(np.random.randn(S, S))
    A[np.diag_indices_from(A)] = -s

    return A
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! My goal is to draw random independent numbers in each off diagonal.  I change the code and I was able to do so. I wrote this based on your example. I am very new to python. `def get_A (S,s, sigma):
   
    A = np.zeros((S, S))
    print(A.dtype)
    
    for i in range(S):
        A[i, i] = - s
    for i in range(1, S):
        for j in range(i):
            a=sigma*abs(np.random.normal(0,1))
            b=sigma*abs(np.random.normal(0,1))
            A[i, j] = a # lower off diagonal
            A[j, i] = b #upper off diagonal
    return A`

Comment: @IsaacJulio There is a simpler way. You can see my updated answer.